# How to switch between Visual Studio default themes? - VS Extension

Tags: visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-addins, vsx, vs-extensibility

All I have found is the [VSColorTheme](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.platformui.vscolortheme.aspx) class which only has ThemeChanged event. But how do I *change* the VS2015 color theme (blue, dark, light)? Is it even possible? Thanks.

Comment: What isn't clear in my question? And how was that "rude" for you?

Comment: The question is clear. He has a VS extension (likely a package) and wants to change programmatically the VS theme (something that manually you would do in Tools > Options, Environment > General section).

Comment: There is the IVsColorThemeService Interface (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.internal.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivscolorthemeservice(v=vs.110).aspx) but it only provides the read-only CurrentTheme property